# What data types do width and style.width accept?

Tags: javascript, html, css, types, width

I am a first time JavaScript student and I have a school question, we need to indicate the data types that width and style.width accept.

I know data types are number, string, null, undefined, boolean and object. We haven't learned to code yet so I don't know how to test my answers nor can I find it on the web.

Comment: The `width` property accepts only String values.

Comment: You would need to explain "where" are we trying to set these types for definitive answers, but as a general rule, most of the properties accept string values pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

The properties on the style object is based on the CSS spec, specified as a String value e.g `element.style.width = '10px'`. As for width, please read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).
More specifically what is eligible to be used, please see [width<length>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) and [width<percentage>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)
If you try to set an invalid value, it will be invalidated and not applied on the element.